# Linux Copy All Files with specific filename length

Tags: linux, terminal, console

I want to Copy all files in my directory with a specific file name length.

e.g.
These files exist:

```
1.py
12.py
123.py
321.py
1234.py
```

Than I want to copy only the files `123.py` and `312.py` (because of length of 3)
I am new to Linux and don´t know how to accomplish this. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to copy files whose names consist of three characters followed by `.py`. This could be done using:

```
cp ???.py destination_directory/
```

(Note: this could fail if you have a very large number, but the limit is typically large on modern systems.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the command find

```
find directory1 -type f -size 3k -exec cp -nv {} directory2/ \;
```